# Change text in legend title and categories R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm new in R and I'm trying to make a bar graph and I need to change the text in legend. I read that I could do it changing the column name, but I need to use Spanish terms, so it's not good idea that kind of words for variable names. Any idea how could I change the text in the legend? Thanks in advance!

PD. I know that my code maybe is not optimal, but it's my first attempt

```
#libs
library(xlsx)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#Import data
reporte<-read.xlsx("PATH",1)

#Change column names
colnames(reporte)<-c("mes","auto","manual","especial","prom")

#Data format for graph
reportem<-melt(reporte[,c("mes","auto","manual","especial")],id.vars=1)

#Fix month order
reportem$mes<-factor(reportem$mes,levels = reportem$mes[order(reportem$variable)])

#Grouped bar chart
g1<-ggplot(data=na.omit(reportem), aes(fill=variable,x=mes, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues",direction=-1) 
+theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = "white",colour = "grey"),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank())

#Add trend line
g2<-g1+geom_line(data=na.omit(reporte),aes(x=mes,y=prom,group=1),colour="red",inherit.aes = FALSE)

#Trend values
g3<-g2+geom_text(data=na.omit(reporte),aes(x=mes,y=prom,group=1,label=prom,vjust=-1),inherit.aes = FALSE)

#Changing title and axis lables
g4<-g3+labs(x="Mes",y="Porcentaje") + ggtitle("Evolución PackInfo")
```

Comment: In your last line, add `...+labs(..., fill = "My fill title", title = "My main title") + ...`

Comment: Thanks Brian, I could change the legend title, but not the legend categories.

This part: ", title = "My main title"" is for change chart title right?

Comment: Where you have: `scale_fill_brewer(...)` add `(..., breaks = c("My first label", "my second label", ...))`

Comment: Did not work. Categories didn't change for the new labels, also the color palette changed...

Comment: I change break for labels and it works! Thanks Brian!